# Show top and bottom alternately in a stack

Tags: c, recursion, stack

I am doing this exercise in which I have to alternately display the element at the top of the stack and then the one at the bottom, until it is empty. I still find it difficult to take advantage of recursion to solve these exercises and I wanted to know if someone could help me. I can't use loops, just recursion.
This are the instructions:
"Given the stack_t abstract data type and its defined operations: create, top, push, pop, elements (returns the number of elements in the stack), destroy:
Complete the one_and_one function that receives a stack and displays the items in the stack alternately starting with the top element and then the bottom element until the stack is empty".
This is what I came up with:

```
void one_and_one(stack_t* stack){

  if(!stack || elements(stack) == 0) return;

  int aux = top(stack);
  pop(stack);
  one_and_one(stack);
  printf("%i\n", aux);
}
```

I still need to figure out how to print the top ones before printing the bottom ones.
I'm going to give an example so it is better understood. If I have the following stack (1 is the top element):
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
The output has to be the following: 1,7,2,6,3,5,4.
Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if it can be possible. Because if you want to access bottom elements of the stack, stack should be empty.

Answer (score 2):

If the operation can be destructive - that is the original stack is not expected to stay intact, then here is an algorithm idea:

1. Display the top of the stack
2. Create another stack
3. Now pop all of the elements from from the original stack and push them into the new stack - except the top one you have already displayed - this will make the new stack to contain the elements in reverse order
4. Call the function recursively on the new stack

Here is a pseudocode:

```
function one_and_one(stack)
    if empty(stack)
        return
    print (pop(stack))        // Step 1
    stack2 = create_stack()   // Step 2
    copy_stack(stack2, stack) // Step 3
    destroy_stack(stack)      // Cleanup
    one_end_one(stack2)       // Step 4


/* This is a helper function for step 3 - recursive as well because no loops allowed*/
function copy_stack(dest, src)
   if not empty(src)
      push(dest, pop(src))
```

P.S. I find it convenient to think about it like a toy stacking pyramid where you are asked to take top and bottom alternately. You take another "empty" pyramid. Take the top piece of the first pyramid, then move the pieces to the other one, one by one. Repeat with the second pyramid. This also hints that you can get away using two stacks only instead of creating one each time.

Comment: Yes! By the end of the function the stack has to be empty. Sorry, I'm going to give an example so it is better understood. If I have the following stack:
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
The output has to be the following: 1,7,2,6,3,5,4.